# Question RE DiscreteMarkovProcess Graph Labels

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, markov-chains

I'm trying to label the arc's of my Markov chain with symbols like $\alpha$, $\beta$, etc., to show how the Markov chain looks abstractly.

So, I did this...

```
    proc = DiscreteMarkovProcess[
     1, {{1/2, 1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {1/2, 1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/2, 1/2, 0, 
      0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}}];
```

And, then this (to try label the arcs)

```
     Graph[proc, EdgeLabels -> {1 <-> 2 -> "\[Alpha]"}]
```

and I'm getting an "error" - Nothing really happens.

```
   Graph[DiscreteMarkovProcess[
       1, {{1/2, 1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {1/2, 1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/2, 1/2, 0, 
       0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}}], 
       EdgeLabels -> {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2 -> "\[Alpha]"}]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for Mathematica 9.0 - The code above appears to work only for Mathematica 10.0.

```
 proc = DiscreteMarkovProcess[
  1, {{1/2, 1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {1/2, 1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/2, 1/2, 0, 
 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}}];
Graph[proc, 
EdgeLabels -> {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> Placed["\[Alpha]", .5], 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 1 -> Placed["1-\[Alpha]", .5], 
 2 \[DirectedEdge] 1 -> Placed[Style["\[Beta]", 12], .5], 
 2 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> Placed["1-\[Beta]", .5], 
 3 \[DirectedEdge] 3 -> Placed["c", .5], 
 3 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> Placed["1-c", .45]}, VertexSize -> 0.15]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `DiscreteMarkovProcess` has directed edges, so you need use the `[DirectedEdge]` version in your `EdgeLabels` specification. In **version 10** the following works:

```
proc = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, 
        {{1/2, 1/2, 0, 0, 0}, 
         {1/2, 1/2, 0, 0, 0}, 
         {0, 1/2, 1/2, 0, 0},
         {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, 
         {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}}];
Graph[proc, 
 EdgeLabels -> {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> Placed[Style["\[Alpha]", 12], {Right, "Middle"}]},
 VertexSize -> 0.15]
```

[image: DMPgraph]

(We can use smaller vertices to make the arrowheads visible.)

According to the comments below, **this does not work in version 9**. It is possible to extract the behavior of `Edgelabels` for `DiscreteMarkovProcess`, though, by fetching the options used to generate the default `Graph` of the discrete Markov process `proc`:

```
Options[Graph[proc]]
```

shows

```
EdgeLabels -> {4 \[DirectedEdge] 5 -> Placed[1, Tooltip], 
               2 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> Placed[1/2, Tooltip], 
               2 \[DirectedEdge] 1 -> Placed[1/2, Tooltip], 
               3 \[DirectedEdge] 3 -> Placed[1/2, Tooltip], ...}
```

Note that `Graph` already has `EdgeLabels` defined for the `DiscreteMarkovProcess` as the transition probabilities placed as tooltips (both the comments below and the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteMarkovProcess.html) seem to indicate that this is true in v9 as well as v10), so the syntax can be extracted and used to produce user-defined labels (although I can't provide the details, so this isn't really a v9 workaround).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.

Comment: You know - I was mistaken - This does not work with my version of Mathematica - (version 9.0) - The graph is not labeled.

Comment: No, it does not work - Bummer

Comment: @Pierre, well, sorry I couldn't help. Best of luck!

Comment: @Pierre, if you check `Options[Graph[proc]]` (for the default graph of your process) you should be able to see the syntax used to generate any `EdgeLabels` that are present by default, and then you could just replace each label with what you want.

Comment: Ok - I tried this - this seems to work..                                                                                                        Graph[proc, 
 EdgeLabels -> {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> Placed["\[Alpha]", .5], 
   1 \[DirectedEdge] 1 -> Placed["1-\[Alpha]", .5], 
   2 \[DirectedEdge] 1 -> Placed["\[Beta]", .5], 
   2 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> Placed["1-\[Beta]", .5], 
   3 \[DirectedEdge] 3 -> Placed["c", .5], 
   3 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> Placed["1-c", .5]}, VertexSize -> 0.15]

Comment: @PierreMFiorini If you have a workaround for V9, please go ahead and add that as answer. (Answering your own question is totally OK).